Unsteady-State Navier-Stokes Conservation of Energy Equation Solution for Cyclinder Heated and Cooled Simultaneously
Hopefully this is the correct place for this sort of question. I'm working on a project for work that requires me to size some heat exchangers for a heating and a second cooling loop. These loops would be used to simultaneously heat the inside of an object while cooling the outside. I wanted to figure out (if possible) the temperature profile within the object over time so that I have an idea of what the maximum loads on the heat exchangers would be and how it would change over time.
I remembered using the Navier-Stokes equation for conservation of momentum in university, but this was always for steady-state problems. I was planning on defining the problem as follows:

It's a cylinder where the hot water flows through the centre of the cylinder (convective heat transfer), then you have material 1 (thickness a), material 2 (thickness b), and material 3 (thickness c) which would only have conductive heat transfer, and then you have cold water on the outside of the cylinder (convective heat transfer).
I was planning on using cyclindrical coordinates, but only care about 1 dimension. So I was going to use the following equation (equation in the centre of the image, simplified in pencil):

But as mentioned above, I'm not sure how to solve it (if there is an analytical solution, numerical works for what I need as well). It's been a long time since I did multivariable calculus so I'm not sure if this is me not remembering how to solve this equation, or if the solution is just very complicated.
Any help would be appreciated.
